# a Django problem: Invalid block tag on line 17: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django

I am reading ，in 4.2 section I got a bug,but I code exactly as it appears in the book.And I did wrire<% load staticfiles %>.
django version 2.1
python version 3.7
[this is the file directory index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/859vP.jpg)

[this is settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuuKo.jpg)

[this is also settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0LXS.jpg)

[this is console and it shows that there is a bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyl6R.jpg)

[this is what browser shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At4IW.jpg)

Comment: I believe you need to add `{% load static %}` at the top of your html template.

Comment: Please add your code inline with the \`\`\` code delimiters.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using `<% load staticfiles %>` which is **wrong**.

Instead you should use `{% load static %}`

Comment: I don't think this will solve the OPs problem - `staticfiles` still works in Django 2.1 which is what they are using (it was removed in Django 3), and the error if you try to use it in Django 3 is different ("`'staticfiles'` is not a registered tag library").

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks, I didn't know `staticfiles` used to be a tag, and updated.   That being said, OP used `<%    %>`, instead of brackets, which are not proper tags, right?

Comment: Oh I had missed the `<% %>`! Yes, that is the problem. Switching to `{% static %}` is also a still good idea as `staticfiles` is removed in Django 3.